# Can I consolidate one file into multiple individual files in pro tools?

Tags: pro-tools

Software: Pro Tools 10

The problem is, 
on one track, i have a very long file which i can trim with STRIP SILENCE.
now i have multiple regions.
On another track, i have the same long file, which i CANT trim with STRIP SILENCE.

is there a way to copy the "multiple region lengths" to the other track?
So i have the "same" (means the same length but different audio) multiple regions like the first track?

hope u know what i mean :)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay theres no quick key or something that does this but theres a hack (Given the tracks are of the same type: ie Audio).

- 1) Duplicate the track you plan on strip silencing to a new track
- 2) Strip silence the original
- 3) With the OBJECT GRABBER tool click and drag to select all the non-contiguous regions that where just created on the original file from strip silence
- 4) With the regions selected click and drag them to the duplicated track you created and press the 'delete' button to get rid of the regions and leave you with the inverse of the regions
- 5) With the OBJECT GRABBER tool click and drag to select all the bog-contiguous regions that where just created
- Drag them to the track that you CANNOT strip silence and press delete

This will leave you with the same breaks in regions as the track you strip silenced on the track that cannot be strip silenced